# Create table list in Xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to generate a product order style table in xamarin forms. I've searched a lot, but I haven't found an example.
As in the attached image.
[image]

Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a DataGrid.  There are several open source and commercial options available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick/professional looking way, you could try Synfucion [DataGrid](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started)

and you also could use [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) to achive the effect.

for example:

```
<StackLayout >
  <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="40" />
          <RowDefinition Height="40" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="My name" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="City" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="MyCity"  BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Address " BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="My Address1234" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Country" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="MyCountry" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```